# How to get path variable in an intercepter

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.2

I am using play framework 2.0, it has a very easy flow... routes -> controllers -> service -> model -> controllers -> result.

Well, following this I have a controller which receives a path variable from the routes.

GET    /user/:userId              controller.user.getUser(userId : String)

As, you can see, this is actually a userId, I want to validate this userId (check whether this exists in our database or not) but not in controller but rather using some annotation, something like this..

```
//My annotation for validating userId
@ValidateUserId(userId)
public static Result getUser(userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this concept is the fact that annotation's params must be a **constant**, @see [topic about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29218835/1066240) so you will be not able to use `userId` like showed in the code. Instead you can create an annotation that reads the context itself, and then parse the URI to get the user's ID. i.e.:

**app/myannotations/MyAnnotations.class**

```
package myannotations;

import play.mvc.With;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;


public class MyAnnotations {

    @With(ValidateUserIdAction.class)
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface ValidateUserId {
        String patternToReplace();
        String redirectTo();
    }

}
```

**app/myannotations/ValidateUserIdAction.class**

```
package myannotations;

import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

import static play.libs.F.Promise;

public class ValidateUserIdAction extends Action<MyAnnotations.ValidateUserId> {

    public Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        boolean isValid = false;

        // This gets the GET path from request
        String path = ctx.request().path();
        try {
            // Here we try to 'extract' id value by simple String replacement (basing on the annotation's param)
            Long userId = Long.valueOf(path.replace(configuration.patternToReplace(), ""));

            // Here you can put your additional checks - i.e. to verify if user can be found in DB
            if (userId > 0) isValid = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exceptions as you want i.e. log it to the logfile
        }

        // Here, if ID isValid we continue the request, or redirect to other URL otherwise (also based on annotation's param)
        return isValid
                ? delegate.call(ctx)
                : Promise.<Result>pure(redirect(configuration.redirectTo()));
    }    
}
```

so you can use it with your action like:

```
@MyAnnotations.ValidateUserId(
   patternToReplace = "/user/", 
   redirectTo = "/redirect/to/url/if/invalid"
)
public static Result getUser(userId){
     ....
}
```

Of course it's very basic sample and you may want/need to make the condition within your validationAction class more sophisticated or add more params to make it even more generic, all is up to you.

Comment: Hi @biesior Thanks, Yeah it is working. but I wanted some way that I could read the parameter that are going to be passed in the methods, so that I don't have to parse the path string. But still thankyou. :)